# Passar variavel para outro form, gerado dinamicamente C#

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma dúvida em relação de passar o valor de um botão para outro form.

tenho o seguinte código

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {


        string cod_evento = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();


        codigo_evento = cod_evento;
        string sql = " select * from eventos where cod_evento = " + cod_evento + " ";

        flowLayoutPanel1.Refresh();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        // MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("erro", "erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);


        }
        else
        {
            int y = 20;
            int incremento = 30;
            int contador = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {


               Button b = new Button();

                b.Name = i.ToString();





                b.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                b.Font = new Font("Verdana", 15);
                string sexo = dt.Rows[i]["sexo"].ToString();

                string tipo = string.Concat(dt.Rows[i]["nome_area"].ToString()," - ",sexo);


                b.Text = string.Concat(sexo.ToString(),  tipo.ToString());
                b.Click += new EventHandler(this.b_Click);


                // vamos carregar para o próximo form




                b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 60);





                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
                flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
                y = y + incremento;
                contador++;
                lblCarregando.Text = "";

            }
        }

    }


      void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Imprimir imprimir = new Imprimir();


        imprimir.sexo = sexo;
        imprimir.tipo = tipo;

        imprimir.cod_evento = codigo_evento;

        // vamos carregar o form com os tipos e quantidades



        imprimir.Show();
        lblCarregando.Text = "";
    }
```

Mas acontece que no loop, ele mostra certinho os valores, mas ao clicar, ele envia para o imprimir o último resultado do loop;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está sobrescrevendo o valor da varíavel `sexo` e `tipo`. Se você quer passar a lista de resultados você tem que popular uma coleção e não uma variável. Sugiro você que crie uma classe.

```
public class Evento
{
    public string Sexo;
    public string Tipo;
}
```

Depois uma lista:

```
List<Evento> dados = new List<Evento>();
```

Dentro do método que você popula as variáveis você troca o código por isso:

```
// código omitido
string sexo = dt.Rows[i]["sexo"].ToString();
string tipo = string.Concat(dt.Rows[i]["nome_area"].ToString()," - ",sexo);

dados.Add(new Evento {
    Sexo = sexo,
    Tipo = tipo
});
```

No seu form `Imprimir` você também cria uma lista do mesmo tipo da que você acabou de popular, depois basta atribuir:

```
imprimir.lista = dados;
```

Comment: Laerte obrigado.
Mas quando eu tento recuperar os valores dela com o dados.count.  ele volta zerado

Comment: A variável você declarou globalmente?

Comment: Sim, declarei globalmente as variaveis

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode passar na inicialização do outro form.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(listaDeDados);
```